# Date Time range sqlalchemy column?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to specify column in Contract Model using Sqlalchemy, Postgres and Flask. Column that indicates contract period (range between two dates) in (day/month/year).

```
class Contract(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'contract'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # contract_period = ?
```

how can i code that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlalchemy supports the Postgresql range types:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#range-types

class sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.DATERANGE

Represent the PostgreSQL DATERANGE type.

So:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import DATERANGE
contract_period = Column(DATERANGE())
```

For more information on Postgresql range types:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-range.html

Answer (score 1):

The following example describe insert and query DATERANGE Column using:SQLAlchemy, psycopg2 and Postgres 12.0

```
class Contract(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'contract'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    contract_period = db.Column(DATERANGE)  # contract_period


def add_contract():
    contract = Contract(
        contract_period=DateRange(date(2021, 1, 1), date(2021, 8, 31)))
    db.session.add(contract)
    db.session.commit()


def query_in_contract_range():
    # returns a value since April 1st is in the range
    contract = Contract.query.filter(
        Contract.contract_period.contains(date(2021, 4, 1))).first()
    print(contract.contract_period)
    print(type(contract.contract_period))


def query_not_in_contract_range():
    # returns nothing because October 1st is not in the range
    contract = Contract.query.filter(
        Contract.contract_period.contains(date(2021, 10, 1))).first()
    if contract:
        print(contract.contract_period)
    return []
```

Thanks Adrian Klaver.

Answer (score 0):

In Sqlalchemy there is type: `db.Datetime`. So it should be:

```py
class Contract(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'contract'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    contract_expiration = db.Column(db.Datetime)
```

**UPD** To get contract period you can simply calculate time between current time and expiration time when you use it.